# Validation error, req.body not defined, it seems the data is being lost between the service and the API

Tags: angular, rest, api

Here's my service file.

```
/* #region  Create of CRUD */
add(name: string) {
const testData = new FormData();
testData.append('title', name);
console.log('name: ' + name);
console.log('testData: ' + testData);
this.http
  .post<{ message: string; test: Test }>(
    'http://localhost:3000/api/tests',
    testData
  )
  .subscribe(responseData => {
    this.router.navigate(['/tests']);
  });
}
/* #endregion */
```

This will output:

```
name: test
testDate: [object FormData]
```

Here's my route file in my API.

```
/* #region  Create of CRUD */
router.post('', (req, res, next) => {
  console.log('Name: ' + req.body.name);
  const test = new Test({
    name: req.body.name
  });
  test.save().then(createdTest => {
    res.status(201).json({
      message: 'Test added successfully',
      test: {
        ...createdTest,
        id: createdTest._id
      }
    });
  });
  }
);
/* #endregion */
```

This will output:

```
Name: undefined
(node:25112) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ValidationError: Test validation failed: name: Path `name` is required.
```

Why would req.body.name be empty at this point?  It seems to be getting lost between going between the application and the API.  Please let me know if there's more code you need for me to include.

Answer (score 0):

In Your FormData Object it looks like you're storing the name variable as 'title'. The first argument of Form data's append function is going to be what the variable in the body is actually called. Try console.logging (req.body.title) in your route file.

FormData Docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/append